# Unexpected (lack of) indentation in C++ end-of-line comments

Tags: indentation, c++

When using C++ mode I've noticed that the `tab` key indents the current line. However, if I'm at the end of the line, I would like to be able to use `tab` to add aligned whitespace so that I can add `//` comments without having to type many spaces manually.

I have tried adding a C++ mode hook with `(setq c++-tab-always-indent nil)` with no results. This is on Emacs 29.1

Is there a way to use `tab` to add whitespace to align a comment in C++ mode?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using `(setq-default c-tab-always-indent nil)` on my init file.